# Could Spider-Man have used his web to get to the source of the suspicious blue blast faster?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, spider-man-homecoming

In Spider-Man: Homecoming, Peter is outside a party, practicing his entrance as Spider-Man, when he sees a suspicious blue explosion in the distance. He takes off to investigate and prepares to launch the web to swing on, but realises that he is aiming at clear sky since there are no high buildings from which to swing. After that, seemingly having no other option, he comedically sprints to the source of the explosion on foot.

I remember that in various Spider-Man video games he could use the web-zip ability to shoot web at an object close to his altitude, then pull and propel himself forwards. In the Ultimate Spider-Man video game there was even a section centered around this mechanic, based in a borough with single two-story houses.

Is such a technique canon outside of video games? Could Spider-Man have actually used it to propel himself against the ground and nearby trees to get to the spot faster?

Comment: Don't know about this version, but in the Sam Raimi trilogy, Spider-Man used his webs on two flag poles to launch himself over to where MJ was being held captive. I think he used this technique a few other times in those movies, but they escape me at the moment.

Comment: Only citing video games seems a folly. Sure, the sprint was comedic. But in a video game, it would not make for good gameplay. The "horizontal launch" seems to be more about creative license to allow the player to reach their objective faster, and skip boring run sequences (which, as a video game developer, makes a lot of sense)

Comment: @Gnemlock that's why I'm asking if such a move appears in other canonical works.

Comment: Spider-Man uses the "web slingshot" trick as early as *Amazing Spider-Man* #1 to chase after the Chameleon, all the way back in 1963.

Comment: “in a video game, it would not make for good gameplay” — yet we are surely just counting the days until *Spider-Man Run* becomes available on all major gaming platforms.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite, indeed, I'm not including games that are literally *genred* as runners, as opposed to open worlds and the like.

Answer (score 2):

## He probably did it off-camera.

Recall that this specific incident was him attempting to cross a golf course, which are intentionally designed with a lot of empty space, so there was literally nothing for Parker to web and grab on to. Looking at the film itself, in the direction he was heading, he had to cross at least ¼-mile or so of green to get to the trees.

Unfortunately for us, the film then cuts to the site of the explosion and doesn't show us the rest of his run there, but I think it's reasonable to assume that he did do something like that after crossing the green.